# Pointer to STL container behaviour

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

I have this class:

```
class Model3D
{
public:
    void AddVert( Vec3D vert ) { vertices.push_back( vert ); }
    void AddTri( Vec3D *v_0, Vec3D *v_1, Vec3D *v_2 );
    void Draw( HDC hdc );

    std::vector<Vec3D> vertices;
    std::vector<Triangle3D> polys;
};
```

Also relevant, the Triangle3D type is defined as follows: (it is small because it's not finished)

```
class Triangle3D
{
public:
    Vec3D  *verts[3];

};
```

Also, Here is AddTri()

```
void Model3D::AddTri( Vec3D *v_0, Vec3D *v_1, Vec3D *v_2 )
{
Triangle3D triangle;
triangle.verts[0] = v_0;
triangle.verts[1] = v_1;
triangle.verts[2] = v_2;

polys.push_back( triangle );
}
```

**Vertices** members are given initial values. Looking at these members in debug through the pointers in **Triangle3D** shows these values correctly

Finally, I attempt to alter the members of **vertices** here:

```
std::vector<Vec3D>::iterator j;

for (j = vertices.begin(); j != vertices.end(); ++j)
    {
    j->x = ( j->x ) / ( j->z );
    j->y = ( j->y ) / ( j->z );
    }
```

After this loop completes, using the debugger, if I inspect the **vertices** vector, the members are modified as hoped. Yet, when I inspect the pointers to these members in the **Triangle3D** class, they are unchanged. Why is this?

**EDIT** here is a snippet of vertices and triangles being added (defines a cube):

```
Model3D Cube( Vec3D center, int size )
{
Vec3D vert;
Model3D model;

vert.z = .5;

vert.x = center.x - (float)( 0.5f * size );
vert.y = center.y + (float)( 0.5f * size );

model.AddVert( vert );

vert.x = center.x + (float)( 0.5f * size );
vert.y = center.y + (float)( 0.5f * size );
model.AddVert( vert );

vert.x = center.x + (float)( 0.5f * size );
vert.y = center.y - (float)( 0.5f * size );
model.AddVert( vert );

vert.x = center.x - (float)( 0.5f * size );
vert.y = center.y - (float)( 0.5f * size );
model.AddVert( vert );

vert.z = 1;
//center.x += 120;
//center.y += 120;

vert.x = center.x - (float)( 0.5f * size );
vert.y = center.y + (float)( 0.5f * size );

model.AddVert( vert );

vert.x = center.x + (float)( 0.5f * size );
vert.y = center.y + (float)( 0.5f * size );
model.AddVert( vert );

vert.x = center.x + (float)( 0.5f * size );
vert.y = center.y - (float)( 0.5f * size );
model.AddVert( vert );

vert.x = center.x - (float)( 0.5f * size );
vert.y = center.y - (float)( 0.5f * size );
model.AddVert( vert );

//front
model.AddTri( &model.vertices[0], &model.vertices[1], &model.vertices[2] );
model.AddTri( &model.vertices[2], &model.vertices[3], &model.vertices[0] );

//top
model.AddTri( &model.vertices[4], &model.vertices[5], &model.vertices[1] );
model.AddTri( &model.vertices[1], &model.vertices[0], &model.vertices[4] );

//bottom
model.AddTri( &model.vertices[3], &model.vertices[2], &model.vertices[6] );
model.AddTri( &model.vertices[6], &model.vertices[7], &model.vertices[3] );

//left

model.AddTri( &model.vertices[4], &model.vertices[0], &model.vertices[3] );
model.AddTri( &model.vertices[3], &model.vertices[7], &model.vertices[4] );

//right
model.AddTri( &model.vertices[1], &model.vertices[5], &model.vertices[6] );
model.AddTri( &model.vertices[6], &model.vertices[2], &model.vertices[1] );

//back
model.AddTri( &model.vertices[5], &model.vertices[4], &model.vertices[7] );
model.AddTri( &model.vertices[7], &model.vertices[6], &model.vertices[5] );

return model;
}
```

And here is the Draw method:

```
void Model3D::Draw( HDC hdc )
{
std::vector<Triangle3D>::iterator i;
std::vector<Vec3D>::iterator j;

for (j = vertices.begin(); j != vertices.end(); ++j)
    {
    j->x = ( j->x ) / ( j->z );
    j->y = ( j->y ) / ( j->z );
    }

for (i = polys.begin(); i != polys.end(); ++i)
    {
    DrawLine( hdc, *i->verts[0], *i->verts[1], WHITE );
    DrawLine( hdc, *i->verts[1], *i->verts[2], WHITE );
    DrawLine( hdc, *i->verts[2], *i->verts[0], WHITE );
    }
}
```

Comment: I see `polys` getting set, but not so much of `vertices`. I recommend building a [mcve]. If that doesn't expose the problem and show you how to fix it, post the [mcve] here.

Comment: Please post a minimal working example.

Comment: I have added the relevant missing code. I believe everything relevant is now posted, as the rest is just windows creation stuff.

Comment: You did not post a [mcve].  You're supposed to post code where we don't have to add any lines of code.  We're supposed to be able to take your code *as-is*, compile it, run it, and see the results.  If we now try to piece together a jigsaw puzzle of code, and start to fill in all of the missing pieces with our own made-up classes, there is a big chance we will never duplicate the error you're seeing.

Comment: @DanMoos Now you have too much code in your example. Please trim it down to just what is needed to demonstrate the problem. Presumably that would involve the code that sets the initial vertices, the code the changes them, an output line (use `std::cout`) to demonstrate that values were not changed, and little else. Hardcode values instead of calculating them.

Comment: @DanMoos -- [This is the work you should have done](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7209bedb3f63b2e).  Take that example, add code to so that your issue is duplicated.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. Its a WIN32 program with associated dead weight. I think everthing that matters is here except maybe for the Vec3D type, which is just a struct with 4 floats (coordinates) as members. I'll see what I can do. Until then, you basically execute the Cube() function, which populates a Model3D with vertices and triangles. The Model3D's Draw() method is called when the window gets updated.

Comment: ok, I'm getting stymied with the formating. Its all there in what I've posted. I understand if you don't want to bother. PaulMcKenzie actually created what I'm trying to create, but attempts to paste it in are foiled (doesn't all format as code, no matter what I do). For what it's worth, I feel that my issue is a fundamental understanding thing, and that its likely obvious to a seasoned coder.

Comment: @DanMoos *if I inspect the vertices vector, the members are modified as hoped. Yet, when I inspect the pointers to these members in the Triangle3D class* -- Do not store pointers of vector elements.  If the vector is resized, those pointers can become invalidated.  Maybe that is what you are seeing -- adding vertices to the vector causes a reallocation to occur, thus those original pointers have now gone up into a puff of smoke.  Just as a test, call `reserve(100)` on that vector of vertices before you start adding items to it.  Do you now get an error?

Comment: What I am referring to are all of these lines: `model.AddTri( &model.vertices[0], &model.vertices[1], &model.vertices[2] );` and then `model.AddTri( &model.vertices[2], &model.vertices[3], &model.vertices[0] );` -- There is no guarantee that, for example, `&model.vertices[0]` has not been changed due to the vector having to reallocate space.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'll try reserving space as you say, but I don't think that is it. First, I don't add/subtract elements once the initial vector is filled, and and the strange behavior happens right after that. Also, when I inspect the pointers, they point to data that is exactly as it should have been prior to the modifications. I'd think it would be garbage if it were a resize thing.  Will try it though...

Comment: I would seriously consider using `std::shared_ptr`, as your code is not specific on which class actually owns those pointers.  This looks like a case of having two pointers, they initially point to the same thing, then you change one expecting the other pointer to just "follow along".

Comment: Just tried the reserve(100) idea. I made a constructor for Model3D that has that line. No change. What it seems like to me is that, although I have an array of pointers in Triangle3D, I am passing in values. In other words, I made copies of vertices, and have pointers to the copies. This suggests my understanding of the pointer syntax is flawed in this case. Also, I am not comfortable with pointers to vector members, for the reasons you stated. But I do want Triangle3D to store indices into the vector. Is there an accepted way to do this?

Comment: Looks like we cross posted, and that you suspect what I suspect. I'll look into shared_ptr, but advisable or not, shouldn't I be able to do what I'm attempting?

Comment: @DanMoos -- This should have been asked earlier -- does your program work?  Maybe what you're seeing is a bug in the debugger, not in your program.  Did you print out the values of those pointers to verify that the pointers haven't changed?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, pass models around by value, or otherwise causing them to get copied? In that case, the copied model would get its own set of `vertices`, but its `polys` would continue to point into the original model's `vertices`.

Comment: My Cube function returns a Mode3D by value...Dang, that makes perfect sense. I'm at work right now, but that is almost certainly what is happening.

Comment: Solved. I had indeed passed by value at one point, and was looking at two different copies of an object. Works a treat now. Thanks Igor for pointing me the right way.